# Python: Aggregate the rows using the column values and delete one row for each key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

I am trying to find a way to remove all duplicated records from my DB.

For example, if I have this table (stored in a CSV file):

```
colA   colB
1      102
2      101
3      101
4      105
5      102
6      101
```

If we aggregate the table using a **groupBy** for the column **colB**, we have:

```
colB   count()
105    1
102    2
101    3
```

The final table I want to receive is:

```
colA   colB
1      102
2      101
3      101
```

- The row with colB=105 is not present since we have only one row in the first table.
- One row with colB=102 is presented since we have two rows in the first table.
- Two rows with colB=101 are presented since we have three rows in the first table.

One more thing: it is not important which row is dropped.

Answer (score 2):

Use, [`Series.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) along with optional parameter `keep=last`:

```
m = df['colB'].duplicated(keep='last')
df = df[m]
```

---

```
# print(df)

   colA  colB
0     1   102
1     2   101
2     3   101
```

Comment: Nice answer. Since OP mentioned he doesn't care about which row is dropped `m = df['colB'].duplicated()` this can also be used. Already upvoted. ;)